# How to reshape vector in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, reshape

I would like to reshape a vector of P*1 elements in a matrix of M*N elements where P = M*N. Using numbers, i have a vector of 143360 and i would like to reshape it in a matrix of 224*640 elements in a most simply way. I'm really new in C++.

Thank's

Comment: the most simple way would be to have different views to the same data (which is simply stored as a linear array). Anyhow, what did you try? SO is not a code writing service, so you need to show some effort before you can get help here

Answer (score 1):

Write a class wrapping the vector.

Some pointers:

- The vector (or a reference to it) should be a member
- You save number of rows and columns
- You access element `(j,i)`, e.g. by returning element `j*columns+i` of the vector
- The accessor functions can have the same name, e.g. `const T& operator()(std::size_t j, std::size_t i) const` for the getter and T& operator()(std::size_t j, std::size_t i)` for the function you use to set certain elements. Having both has the advantage you can use the getter when passing your matrix as const.
- As hinted already, you might want to template your class, so you can use it with several datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: If the size of your matrix is not fix you can use a `std::vector` to store the data. If it is fixed you can use a `std::array`.

Then you can write a getter like

```
double get_component(std::size_t c1, std::size_t c2){
    return matrix [ c1 * M + c2 ];
}
```

**BUT:** I recommend to have a look at linear algebra libraries, such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [Amadrillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/). They deliver the usability you are searing for and offer highly elaborated storing and calculation abilities. I doubt that you can out run the performance of these libraries.

Comment: "If it is fixed you can use a `std::vector`."  This is true, but I *strongly* suspect you meant "... can use a `std::array`" :-)

Comment: Also, missing `)` on the return statement (and actually, should probably be `[]`).

Comment: @MartinBonner you are perfectly right. I edited my answer.

Comment: also not clear what class the getter should belong to? `std::vector` ? Of course not, but the answer is somehow incomplete